# React state not updating after await - useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update multiple file upload status but after await not updating to any state

```
const uploadFiles = async() => {
  let tradeFileListNew = [...tradeFileList];

  for (const fileList of tradeFileListNew) {
    if (fileList.status == "not-yet") {
      let index = tradeFileListNew.indexOf(fileList);
      tradeFileListNew[index].status = "started";
      setTradeFilesToUpload(tradeFileListNew);

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", fileList.file);
      formData.append("service_type", "attachments");

      let res = await api.uploadCompanyFile(formData);
      tradeFileListNew[index].status = "completed";
      setTradeFilesToUpload(tradeFileListNew);


    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Notice you're calling `setTradeFilesToUpload(tradeFileListNew);` multiple times, and attempting to mutate `tradeFileListNew` in between. React is going to ignore the second call to `setTradeFilesToUpload` because it's passed the same reference, so it's assumed to be a no-op.

Comment: Please advice me that how to update file uploaded status asynchronously I have to update every file upload done, Not single time

Comment: Ok I got it the solution is setTradeFilesToUpload([...tradeFileListNew]);